# How can I trigger ResizeObserver from a Jasmine test?

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have the following component which utilizes `ResizeObserver` (via https://www.npmjs.com/package/@juggle/resize-observer)

```
export class ResizeTestComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public hostRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => this.resized());
    resizeObserver.observe(this.hostRef.nativeElement);
  }

  resized() {
    console.log('resized');
  }
}
```

If I change the window width manually, the component width changes and `resized` is output to the console via the `resized` function, as expected.

I want to write a Jasmine test to check if the `resized` function is called when the element is resized.

How do I trigger the `resizeObserver`?

I have tried sending a `resize` event but the `resized` function is not called:

```
 it('resized function is called when element is resized', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ResizeTestComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const resizedSpy = spyOn(fixture.componentInstance, 'resized');
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
    
    expect(resizedSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-with-jasmine-f3vgbg?file=app%2Fresize-test.component.spec.ts

Comment: If you have a look on how juggle is testing their code they try to manipulate the element itselft. So in you case you could try to change the style of the observed element.

https://github.com/juggle/resize-observer/blob/v3/test/inline-elements.test.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit tricky to test this you need so simulate an actual resize of of the component. Also the `ResizeObserver` runs outside the control of Angular so it behave strangely inside the tests. Your component registers the `ResizeObserver` to the component element which is not present at all in the HTML when you test the component directly. Because of this you need to perform this testing by using a wrapper component.

Here is my suggestion on how to test this.

```
describe('HostTestComponent', () => {
  @Component({
    selector: 'test-host',
    template: `<resize-test></resize-test>`,
    styles: [':host { width: 300px }'],
  })
  class HostComponent {}

  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HostComponent>;

  beforeAll(() => {
    TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
      BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
      platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
    );
  });
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      declarations: [ResizeTestComponent, HostComponent],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HostComponent);
  }));
  it('resized function is called when element is resized', async(() => {
    const resizeTestComponentDebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(
      By.directive(ResizeTestComponent)
    );
    const resizedSpy = spyOn(
      resizeTestComponentDebugElement.componentInstance,
      'resized'
    );
    resizedSpy.and.callThrough();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    setTimeout(() => { // process first resize when component is first drawn
      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.style.width = '200px';
        fixture.detectChanges();
        setTimeout(() => { // process resize due to width change.
          fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            expect(resizedSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
          });
        }, 0);
      });
    }, 0);
  }));
});
```

As you can see I create the wrapper component and then change the width of the wrapper component that triggers a resize in the component. Also in this scenario actually two resize events happen first time on the initial draw of the component and the second on the actual resize. This is because the `ngOnInit` is called before the component is drawn.

Here is also a [link to a fork of you StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-with-jasmine-w1gwld?file=app%2Fresize-test.component.spec.ts) where you can see it working.

Comment: nice, thanks very much for this

Comment: In my case, the resizeObserver is triggered but only after the expects run. Is there a way to wait a bit ?

Comment: You can try to increase the timeout in `setTimeout` from 0 to a bigger number if this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you need to actually resize the element, not simply fire the `resize` event.

That is, you actually have to change the width, height or both.

So try the following.

```
 it('resized function is called when element is resized', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ResizeTestComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const resizedSpy = spyOn(fixture.componentInstance, 'resized');

    // this or some fixed values e.g. 800, 600.
    window.resizeTo(
      window.screen.availWidth / 2,
      window.screen.availHeight / 2
    );

    expect(resizedSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

Comment: Thanks, however using your code in the stackblitz it still fails so I've awarded the other working answer.